# javascript localstorage data duplicating over array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, local-storage

I'm creating a workday task scheduler. I'm able to pull my data from localstoage.
Now I'm trying to iterate through an array of objects, and if that id matches retrieve that data.
Each object has 2 properties, **hour** & **description**. I'm using hour as the unique identifer.
When I retreive the data from localstorage it's duplicating the targeting object data in every textarea.

**How do I just have it display in the textarea with only the matching id?**

Here's the area of the code I think is giving me the problem

```
for ( var i = 0; i < timeBlockArr.length; i++) {

  var timeBlockId = $(".time-block").attr("id");
  if(timeBlockArr[i].hour === timeBlockId) {    
    $(".time-block .description").val(timeBlockArr[i].description);
  }
}
```

and the js fiddle of the working project https://jsfiddle.net/j9hepL2b/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating through your localStorage objects, so the value of `timeBlockId` is not affected by the localStorage element you are currently processing.

In this line, `$(".time-block")` is an array of your elements with the `time-block` class.

```
var timeBlockId = $(".time-block").attr("id");
```

But jQuery's `.attr()` method only returns the ID of the first element in that array. From [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/attr/):

> The .attr() method gets the attribute value for only the first element in the matched set.

Therefore: `console.log(timeBlockId)` is always `"hour-9"`.

If I understand what you're trying to do, you shouldn't need the `if` statement at all. Try this:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < timeBlockArr.length; i++) {

    const selector = '#' + timeBlockArr[i].hour + ' .description';

    $(selector).val(timeBlockArr[i].description);
  
}
```

I.e. you select the element with the class `.description` (the textarea) which is the descendant of the element with the ID `#hour-9`, `#hour-10` etc. and amend that textarea's value with `.val()`.